# Pass the informations of my logged user to my conttroller using Laravel JetStream

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-jetstream

I'm using the authentication given by JetStream in my application.
I saw I could use the Auth facade and when I try it from a Jetstream file it works (for exemple I tried on the Fortify's action "UpdateUserPassword" to add a dd with Auth::user()->id and it indeed shows the id of my logged user).

But as soon as I tried this command from one of my controllers, I receive the message: "Attempt to read property "id" on null". So if I understand well, my controller doesn't get the loggedd in user... But why would it work on the Fortify action and not on my controller?

For more informations, the code I put on my controller was called from an api route ( I used postman to call the function), whereas the dd from the Fortify action was called directly from the Html view given by JetStream in which I added a dd.

Do I need to import a specific library in my controller? Or is it just a logical mistake that I don't understand yet?
Thanks

EDIT: Here is my api routes:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\FileController;
use App\Http\Controllers\FolderController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware([
    'auth:sanctum',
    config('jetstream.auth_session'),
    'verified'
])->group(function () {
    Route::get('user', fn () => auth()->user());
    Route::resource('files', FileController::class)->only([
        'destroy', 'show', 'store', 'update'
    ]);

    Route::resource('folders', FolderController::class)->only([
        'index', 'destroy', 'show', 'store', 'update'
    ]);
});
```

With FileController and FolderController, the controllers I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using an api or your auth using laravel sanctum (jetstream using sanctum by default), you should add the middleware in your route,

i recognize this when i building an api and i want to get this current user, i get same error like you, maybe this will work.

api.php / web.php

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('user', fn () => auth()->user());
    // other controller 
    // ...
    // other controller
});
```

Comment: I now get the Unauthenticated message on postman for the api even if I'm logged in on my view

Comment: did you add your token in postman? https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#bearer-token

Comment: Yes, in Postman in Authorization I put the bearer token filled with my API token, and I added tha Accept application/json parameter in the headers section

Comment: I edited my questtion with the different routes I now have